# Cannot set property 'value' of null when using getElementById

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to auto-change the maximum value of an input field automatically using a tampermonkey script, this is the code of said input feild:

```
<input id="nick" class="form-control" placeholder="Nick" maxlength="15" autofocus>
```

The maximum value of the input field is 15, im trying to have it auto-change it to 100 every time i reload the page by using this code:

`document.getElementById("nick").value = "100";`

For some reason this does not work, i tried setting the "id" to "maxLength" instead but then i get this error, "Cannot set property 'value' of null"
How can I get it to change the input field to 100 every time but not get this error? Thanks for your time.

Comment: where are you including the script?

Comment: The script either has to come *after* you've declared the `input` or you need to register a callback for when the DOM is ready.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Comment: Shouldn't you be changing `maxLength`, not `value`? Seems like a typo to me.

Answer (score 0):

Use [**`maxLength`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/maxlength) property, not `value`.

> ***`HTMLInputElement.maxLength`***: The maximum number of characters that the textbox allows to be entered.

```js
document.getElementById("nick").maxLength = "100";
```

```html
<input id="nick" class="form-control" placeholder="Nick" maxlength="15" autofocus>
```